# WP_User_Query and user posts

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, wp-user-query

I queried a list of users using WP_User_Query from which I got the avatar, name and a few ACF that I created for the user registration.

Now, I need to obtain a post list of each of the users in my results but I don't know how to do it.

This is my query WITHIN WP_User_Query:

```
$postArgs = array (
                'author__in'=> array(2,4,6), //Authors's id's you like to include
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
            );

            $postsquery = new WP_Query ( $postArgs); 

            while ( $postsquery->have_posts() ) : $postsquery->the_post();
echo '
        <li class="viral-note">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> <img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . '" alt="" class="square-mini img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <span class="catego-tag">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</span> </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <span class="excerpt">' . get_the_title() . '</span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>';
            endwhile;wp_reset_query();
```

How can I store the users from my first query into an array and then pass it onto my second query?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in the `fields` parameter to your user query you can easily get an array of ids to the pass in to your wp query :

```
//WP User Query
$author_query = new WP_User_Query( array (
    'number' => 3,
    'fields' => 'ID'
));

$author_results = $author_query->results;   

//WP Query
$postArgs = array (
    'author__in'=> $author_results,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
);
```